# Is there any simple way to store the previous intent value in Bot Framework SDKv4 to make use of with current utterance entities?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-bot-service

Can anyone help me with how to proceed with storing of an intent from previous utterance and binding it to the current entities from the current utterance? In short the context management using available state objects? Thank you.

Like in v3

```
Context.UserData.SetValue("intent_name",intent);
string previousIntent = Context.UserData.GetValue<string>("intent_name");
```

How is this done in  V4?

Comment: Can you add some more information to help make this question easier to narrow down? You say "SDKv4" but what SDK is this? Is this some speech/AI API?

Comment: SDKv4 I mean for bots  built by using Dot Net Core

Answer (score 2):

In v4 you can get the state properties from the turn context.

Sample:

```
var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());
```

That is defined on OnMessageActivityAsync Task event, which derived from ActivityHandler class. You can see more sample details at [StateManagementBot.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/45.state-management/Bots/StateManagementBot.cs) from [BotBuilder-Sample StateManagement](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/45.state-management) project.

And this is the [Differences between the v3 and v4 .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-about?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

> v4 doesn't use UserData, ConversationData, and PrivateConversationData properties and data bags to manage state. ​State is managed via state management objects and property accessors. v4 defines UserState, ConversationState, and PrivateConversationState classes that manage state data for the bot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It means, the conversation state in default holds the data related to intent and entities of a conversation or do we need create those custom properties by using SetValue and retrieve them by using GetValue ? Thank you

Comment: State management automates the reading and writing of bot's state to the underlying storage layer. State is stored as state properties, which are effectively key-value pairs that bot can read and write through the state management object. Those state properties define how that information is stored. For example, when you retrieve a property that you defined as a specific class or object, you know how that data will be structured. To see more about managing state... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0